# I didnt get a result like True or False,where did ı go wrong?

Tags: python

Question is: Write a program that takes three integers from the user. Then pass these three integers to a function findIfTriangle(). In this function test if those three
numbers can be a triangle. If yes, return and print True. If not, return and print False.

Function structure:`boolean findIfTriangle(list)`

```
num1 = int(input("put a number: "))
num2 = int(input("put a number: "))
num3 = int(input("put a number: "))

def findIfTriangle(n1,n2,n3):
    if (n1 + n2 < n3) or (n2+n3 < n1) or (n1 + n3 < n2):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    print(findIfTriangle(num1,num2,num3))
```

Comment: you call `findIfTriangle` in each call to `findIfTriangle` (in the print function) and hence get an endless loop.

Comment: Since the function is boolean you should return True or False rather than have a print.    As commented you don't want to recursively call the function.

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: I can't see where you are calling `findIfTriangle` in your code. You only declared it.
You might want to add this line:
`print(findIfTriangle(num1,num2,num3))`

Comment: You just need to call findIfTriangle and print "True" or "False" based upon the result.

Comment: I see you have edited the text of your question and changed your code to make more sense. Did you have a question?

Comment: Yeah,I am beginner in python.So ı did not understand clearly.Where should ı put something to get a result?

Comment: Did you mean to add the line: `findIfTriangle(num1, num2, num3)` ?

Comment: yep, ı tried to fit it somewhere,but ı get  nothing.

Comment: Please update your question with the *actual* code you are trying to run. Please don't make us **guess**  where the problem lies.

Comment: Ok, I see you have edited your question. If this is the *actual* code, then your last line is indented when it shouldn't be. See the answer from @Sachinkumar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion, you should try this:

```
num1 = int(input("put a number: "))
num2 = int(input("put a number: "))
num3 = int(input("put a number: "))

def findIfTriangle(n1,n2,n3):
    return (n1 + n2 > n3) and (n2 + n3 > n1) and (n1 + n3 > n2)

print(findIfTriangle(num1, num2, num3))
```

Comment: Hey! You don't need the if-else statement. You could just do `return (n1 + n2 > n3) and (n2 + n3 > n1) and (n1 + n3 > n2)`!

Comment: @ZombieChibiXD, Yeah!

Answer (score -1):

You could define the findIfTriangle like this:

```
def findIfTriangle(n1,n2,n3):
    if (n1 + n2 < n3) or (n2+n3 < n1) or (n1 + n3 < n2):
        print("false")
    else:
        print("true")
```

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to call the function again while printing true/false. Since there is no condition as well that will stop your function call at some point in time , it is being recursively called infinitely. Define your function like this:

```
    def findIfTriangle(n1,n2,n3):
        if (n1 + n2 < n3) or (n2+n3 < n1) or (n1 + n3 < n2):
            print("false")
        else:
            print("true")
```